# Need help migrating from the object notation for "createSlice.extraReducers" to the 'builder callback' notation using Typescript

Tags: redux-toolkit, react-typescript, rtk-query, next.js13

So I got a warning from redux-toolkit about using the object notation for the `createSlice.extraReducers` notation.

I would need to implement it for my 'NextJS/Typescript project.

And I would like to mention that I've tried looking for resources online regarding the issue, but my attempts were all futile.

Here's the warning:
`The object notation for` createSlice.extraReducers `is deprecated, and will be removed in RTK 2.0. Please use the 'builder callback' notation instead`

So I tried writing it this way:

```
 extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(HYDRATE, (state, action: PayloadAction<AuthState>) => {
        return {
          ...state,
          ...action.payload,
        };
      })
      .addCase();
  },

//AuthState is an interface that defines  my initialState for this reducerSlice
```

Here's the Error message I kept getting:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(actionCreator: TypedActionCreator<string>, reducer: CaseReducer<AuthState, Action<string>>): ActionReducerMapBuilder<AuthState>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TypedActionCreator<string>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(type: "__NEXT_REDUX_WRAPPER_HYDRATE__", reducer: CaseReducer<AuthState, Action<"__NEXT_REDUX_WRAPPER_HYDRATE__">>): ActionReducerMapBuilder<AuthState>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(state: WritableDraft<AuthState>, action: { payload: AuthState; type: string; }) => { loggedIn: boolean; userId: string; role: string; accessToken: string; refreshToken: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CaseReducer<AuthState, Action<"__NEXT_REDUX_WRAPPER_HYDRATE__">>'.
      Types of parameters 'action' and 'action' are incompatible.
        Property 'payload' is missing in type 'Action<"__NEXT_REDUX_WRAPPER_HYDRATE__">' but required in type '{ payload: AuthState; type: string; }'.
```